# Theorem 1.1.30 in Huybrechts's Complex geometry

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry

I am looking for a reference on the following theorem cited in Huybrechts's book *Complex geometry* (Theorem  1.1.30), which stated in the book without a proof.

**Theorem**
Let $X \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be an irreducible analytic germ
defined by a prime ideal
$\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}.$
Then one can find a coordinate system
$$(z_1 , \ldots , z_{n-d},z_{n-d+1} ,\ldots , z_n )$$
such that the projection
$(z_1 , \ldots , z_n) \mapsto (z_{n-d+1} ,\ldots , z_n )$
induces a surjective map (of germs!)
$\pi:X \to \mathbb{C}^d$
and such that the induced ring homomorphism
$ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^d,0} \to  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}/\mathfrak{p}$
is a finite integral ring extension.

Comment: is it from Noether normalization lemma?

Comment: @Ben: No (even though it is the motivation), since the context is complex-analytic, not algebraic.  So one has to make essential use of the circle of ideas related to analytic quasi-finite maps and the dimension theory of analytic local rings. In the awesome book *Coherent Analytic Sheaves*, see: section 3.4 of Ch. 3 (especially the "Existence Theorem" there), section 1.3 of Ch. 4 for the notion of "irreducibility" at a point used there (encoding $\mathfrak{p}$ being prime above), and sections 3.2--3.3 of Chapter 2 to handle stalks for maps with finite fibers. Read the whole book; it's great!

Comment: @nfdc23: Thanks a lot. I will read that book.