A far reaching generalization of the WPT?
I encountered the the Nullstellensatz for Germs of Holomorphic Functions in Daniel Huybrechts' Complex Geometry: An Introduction, specifically Proposition 1.1.29

If $I\subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$ is any ideal, then $\sqrt{I}=I(Z(I))$.

If suffices to show that $I(Z(I))\subset \mathfrak{p}$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ containing $I$. The book provides the following statement:

...If we know already that $\mathfrak{p}=\sqrt{\mathfrak{p}}=I(Z(\mathfrak{p}))$ for all prime ideals, this follows from $Z(\mathfrak{p})\subset Z(I)$.
In order to prove the assertion for prime ideals we need an important result on the structure of irreducible analytic germs which could be considered as a far reaching generalization of the WPT (Proposition 1.1.6). As the formulation of this theorem is already quite involved and its proof is rather lengthy, we will not attempt to present it here. We will state the following theorem without proof. It should, however, be noted that we actually present only two aspects of the full result.

Theorem 1.1.30 is then given as:

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an irreducible analytic germ defined by a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$. Then one can find a coordinate system $$(z_1, \ldots, z_{n-d}, z_{n-d+1}, \ldots, z_n)$$ such that the projection $(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \mapsto (z_{n-d+1}, \ldots, z_n)$ induces a surjective map (of germs!) $\pi: X \to \mathbb{C}^d$, and such that the induced ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^d,0} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite integral ring extension.

My questions are:

What exactly is the "full result" that is referenced but not completely stated in the book?
Where can I find the "lengthy" proof that is not presented here?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

See https://mathoverflow.net/q/255620/
